# Java word filter using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a word filter where a user can replace certain words with others. However, there are obviously some things that I don't want it to filter (words that are apart of other words, for example).

So far I have this:

```
msg = msg.replaceAll("(?i)\\b[^\\w -]*"+original+"[^\\w -]*\\b", replacement);
```

It, for the most part, works relatively well. However, there is one small glitch.

When I replace "m" with, let's say, "r" then it also replaces the "m" in words like "I'm" - which means it becomes "I'r", which is obviously a bug.

I hope you understand what I mean. Help?

Comment: would you please add the original msg which you are testing against and your expected result please, this way we might be able to better help you. Thanks

Comment: You could first substitute all apostrophed [contractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29) to their full form.

Comment: Also consider quoting the original word: `java.util.Pattern.quote(original).toString()`.

Comment: The default operation of MS Word replace function is to replace any instance of one given string (case insensitive) with the other given string, even if the found string resides inside of another word. By doing so, MS shifts the responsibility to define this behavior to the user.  

For example, if we have "smiles", and do a replace "miles" -> "nozzberries", we will get a result of "snozzberries". If the user wants to only replace a *word* match of "miles" and not a *substring* match, they'd do a search/replace for " miles ", note the extra spaces.  

Can you shift responsibility to the user?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
//If "X-Men" counts as one word:
msg = msg.replaceAll("(?i)(?<![\\w'-])"+original+"(?![\\w'-])", replacement);
//If "X-Men" counts as two words:
msg = msg.replaceAll("(?i)(?<![\\w'])"+original+"(?![\\w'])", replacement);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks. I think that I was just struggling with the syntax a little bit.